# Обязательные поля c#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, xamarin.forms

Приложение кроссплатформенное, есть **форма** и в ней обязательные поля в данный момент речь идет о **UWP_XamarinForms**.

Eсть идеи как **поля** обводить **красным** в момент сохранения и внизу каждого поля сообщение "...****обязательное поле*" ...ну что то в этом духе

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required.")]
public object Title; // не подходит
```

хотелось бы обойти Model и только в ViewModel подправить, вопрос больше по дизайну // создать Control...

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.php

Comment:  нет доступа к TextBox, по-моему это чистый UWP
оч симпатично, жаль
ищу эквивалент...